# About positive functions on an infinite set

Tags: measure-theory

Let $F\in BV([0,1])$, $F\geq 0$, and $F\gt 0$ on an infinite set.

Can we have $F=0$ almost everywhere w.r.t. Lebesgue measure?

I'd like to say no but I can't prove it...

Comment: What is $BV([0,1])$?

Comment: @muzzlator: see definition 1.2 in en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_variation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, we can. Take a kind of Dirichlet-type function
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
1&\hbox{ for } x\in Q \cap [0,1]\\
0&\hbox{ for } x\in (R\setminus Q)\cap [0,1]
\end{cases}
$$
This function is greater than zero on a countable set, but it is equal zero almost everywhere.

Comment: This function does not seem to have bounded variation.

Comment: That depends on the definition of bounded variation. If you take pointwise bounded variation I agree. But the usual definition is the function is of bounded variation if $\sup_{\phi\in C^{1}_{c}([0,1]), \|\phi\|_{L^{\infty}(0,1)}\leq  1} \int_{0}^{1}\phi'(x)f(x)\ dx $ is finite. Then this function is zero almost everywhere with respect to the Lebesgue measure and therefore...of bounded variation(if I am not wrong). So the question of muzzlator seems very reasonable.

Comment: Hmm, interesting, I don't know your definition. The definition I learned is equivalent to "a difference of two monotonous functions".

Comment: yeah, if you use this definition it is the pointwise definition (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_variation) and then you are right. The problem is that in Lebesgue measure a function which is only on an countable or on a set with lebesgue measure zero unequal to zero, has the same representative as the zero function...

Comment: The definition I had in mind when writing this question is the definition 1.2 in the wikipedia link above.

Comment: Hm, then what abount the function $f(x)=\begin{cases} \tfrac{1}{n^{2}} &\hbox{ for } x=1-\tfrac{1}{n},\ n\in N\\0 &\hbox{else} \end{cases}$. This function is zero a.e. and its total variation is finite, since $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \tfrac{1}{n^{2}}$ converges.

Comment: @Alex: yes it is a nice example. What if we require the set where F > 0 to be uncountable?

Comment: I dont know. There are sets with Lebesgue measure zero but uncountable (for instance the cantor set), butI do not know how we could construct a counterexample...maybe this is impossible :).

Answer (score 0):

Just take $F := \sum_{k=0}^\infty {\mathbb{1}_{\{2^{-k}\}} 2^{-k}}$.